# ASP.NET MVC 3 user authorization issue in session_start() function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My application uses `Identity claim authentication` (Active directory user account) to let user access the application pages.

I am trying to change the routing information in the `session_start()` function, so that if a logged in user is in a non-admin role then i can redirect him to an "Access Denied" page.

I have tried to change the routing info in this function. But i cannot able to do that.

Any suggestions? or what i am doing wrong in this?

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing authentication this way, I would suggest you to follow the simple way of doing the authentication per controller basis. Like following

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class StoreManagerController : Controller
```